# How to pass a Windows path as a value using the Perl Tie::Cfg module

Tags: perl, config, tie

Iam using the [`Tie::Cfg`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::Cfg) module for getting user details in my automation.

Problem/Issue:

I have a configuration file which accept user details and path. I am able to print values from the configuration file in Linux, but in the case of Windows, due to backslashes I cannot get the correct value.

for example: `/root/devel/Conf.ini`

```
user=test
password=config
path_linux=\home\basic\
path_wind=C:\Users\rakesh\Documents
```

I created a module `/root/devel/test.pm`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Cfg;
use parent 'Exporter';

tie our %conf,'Tie::Cfg', READ =>"Conf.ini", WRITE=> "Conf.ini", MODE=> 0777;
our @EXPORT = qw(%conf);
1;
```

In my third Perl script `/root/devel/local.pl` I am just printing the   configuration values:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tie::Cfg;

print "date : $conf{path_linux} and path : $conf{path_wind} \n";
```

Output:

```
$conf{path_linux} = \home\basic\
$conf{path_wind} = C:SERSRAKESHDOCUMENTS
```

Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

[`Tie::Cfg`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::Cfg) applies a `eval` to the data in the config file, so it is treated as a double-quoted Perl string. For instance, the `\r` in `\rakesh` is converted to a carriage-return.

You can make use of [`Tie::Config`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::Config) instead, which leaves the data untouched. You would write

```
use Tie::Config;
use Fcntl '/O_*/';
tie our %conf,'Tie::Config', O_RDWR;
```

or you can stick with `Tie::Cfg` and escape all the backslashes in your config file, like this

```
user=test
password=config
path_linux=/home/basic
path_wind=C:\\Users\\rakesh\\Documents
```

Comment: i tried the 2nd solution mentioned earlier it works fine,but problem is if you edit hash ,i mean if you try to added new key:value in hash.The "path_wind" key get modified to value C:SERSRAKESHDOCUMENTS again. not sure why it is doing so.under /local.pl                                                                                                   tie our %conf,'Tie::Cfg',READ =>"MyConfig.ini",WRITE =>  "MyConfig.ini",MODE=>0777;
$conf{Counter}=$size;
our @EXPORT=qw(%conf);
untie %conf;
In the above code,adding new key:value to hash after this change original problem is back